# What does ものでして mean?

Tags: grammar

I can't manage to understand the meaning of ものでして.

An example using a full sentence could be the following:

> 私はしばらく、隠棲していたものでしてね。まあ怠けているのは今に始まったことでもなし・・・

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the sentence you provided, 'ものでして' can be translated to 'i was in the state of~'.
So that means some person's previous state or condition.

'ものでして' can also be used to introduce yourself with what you are doing for living.

ex.
私は大阪で靴の商売をしている**ものでして**...
I make living out of selling shoes in Osaka...

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the context, but this …ものでして is probably a polite form of …もので ([Daijirin](http://dic.yahoo.co.jp/dsearch?enc=UTF-8&stype=1&dtype=0&dname=0ss&p=%E3%82%82%E3%81%AE%E3%81%A7), [Daijisen](http://dic.yahoo.co.jp/dsearch?enc=UTF-8&p=%E3%82%82%E3%81%AE%E3%81%A7&dtype=0&dname=0na&stype=1&pagenum=1&index=18310900)), which means “because …” and is similar to …ので.  The main clause is completely omitted, probably because the omitted part is clear from the context.  If this interpretation is correct, the first sentence in the quoted text means:

> 私はしばらく、隠棲していたものでしてね。  It is because I was leading a secluded life for a while.

Answer (score 0):

It's もの as in person "者" plus "desu" in te form "deshite".