# What does Noun でして mean?

Tags: particle-で

> その鋼の心を支えるものこそ酒でして

The character in question is asking for a drink and says.

What does でして mean here?

Comment: Gramatically, it's a te-form of the auxiliary verb です.

Comment: Related, perhaps? https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/55870/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/11287/9831

Comment: also just wanna explain that motte shite is the particle with shite and motte that changes kanji to suit the meaning but still like a particle

Comment: Does this answer your question? [て form at end of phrase but not being used for requests](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/60762/%e3%81%a6-form-at-end-of-phrase-but-not-being-used-for-requests) It's probably 言いさし that you're asking about, but this is hard to explain without checking the entire context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The でして is actually 2 separate things. It is the particle で and する in the て form

The で can be seen as meaning "by means of" or "with". Where the して is a more firm / direct version of してください

Taking the context at face value, the character is saying something like:

> Give me a drink that's for this heart of steel
>
> More literal: (please) do something with alcohol that supports this heart of steal